# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' error en python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, combobox

Tengo un error en mi código de python y no sé qué hacer. He intentado ya muchísimas cosas y no doy con la solución:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' error

en python, y es que cuando abro la primera venta del combobox que es la de n masico y n atomico, introduzco cualquier valor en los entru, y al darle al botón solución me sale el error. Aquí os dejo el código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def salir():
     ventana.destroy()

def obtener_info():
     if lista_desplegable.get()=="N masico y N atomico":
          def solucion():
               var1=NmasicoE.get()
               var2=NatomicoE.get()
               numpro=NatomicoE.get()
               numelec=NatomicoE.get()
               numneu=var1-var2

               print("{} N.atomico".format(NatomicoE.get()))
               print("{} N.masico".format(NmasicoE))
               print("{} protones".format(numpro))
               print("{} electrones".format(numpro))
               print("{} neutrones".format(numneu))

          ventana2=Tk()
          ventana2.title("N masico y N atomico")

          miframe2=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe2.pack()

          miframe3=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe3.pack()

          Nmasico=Label(miframe2,text="N masico:")
          Nmasico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
          Natomico=Label(miframe2,text="N atomico:")
          Natomico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=0,sticky="w")

          NmasicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NmasicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=1,sticky="e")
          NatomicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NatomicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=1,sticky="e")

          botonsolucion=Button(miframe3,text="Solucion",command=solucion)
          botonsolucion.grid(padx=10,pady=10)

          ventana2.mainloop()

     if lista_desplegable.get()=="N masico y N protones":
          
          ventana2=Tk()
          ventana2.title("N masico y N protones")

          miframe2=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe2.pack()

          miframe3=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe3.pack()

          Nmasico=Label(miframe2,text="N masico:")
          Nmasico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
          Nprotones=Label(miframe2,text="N protones:")
          Nprotones.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=0,sticky="w")

          NmasicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NmasicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=1,sticky="e")
          NprotonesE=Entry(miframe2)
          NprotonesE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=1,sticky="e")

          botonsolucion=Button(miframe3,text="Solucion")
          botonsolucion.grid(padx=10,pady=10)

          ventana2.mainloop()
     
     if lista_desplegable.get()=="N masico y N electrones":
          
          ventana2=Tk()
          ventana2.title("N masico y N electrones")

          miframe2=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe2.pack()

          miframe3=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe3.pack()

          Nmasico=Label(miframe2,text="N masico:")
          Nmasico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
          Natomico=Label(miframe2,text="N atomico:")
          Natomico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=0,sticky="w")

          NmasicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NmasicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=1,sticky="e")
          NatomicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NatomicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=1,sticky="e")

          botonsolucion=Button(miframe3,text="Solucion")
          botonsolucion.grid(padx=10,pady=10)

          ventana2.mainloop()

     if lista_desplegable.get()=="N masico y N neutrones":
          
          ventana2=Tk()
          ventana2.title("N masico y N neutrones")

          miframe2=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe2.pack()

          miframe3=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe3.pack()

          Nmasico=Label(miframe2,text="N masico:")
          Nmasico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
          Natomico=Label(miframe2,text="N atomico:")
          Natomico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=0,sticky="w")

          NmasicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NmasicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=1,sticky="e")
          NatomicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NatomicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=1,sticky="e")

          botonsolucion=Button(miframe3,text="Solucion")
          botonsolucion.grid(padx=10,pady=10)

          ventana2.mainloop()

     if lista_desplegable.get()=="N atomico y N neutrones":
          
          ventana2=Tk()
          ventana2.title("N atomico y N neutrones")

          miframe2=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe2.pack()

          miframe3=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe3.pack()

          Nmasico=Label(miframe2,text="N masico:")
          Nmasico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
          Natomico=Label(miframe2,text="N atomico:")
          Natomico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=0,sticky="w")

          NmasicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NmasicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=1,sticky="e")
          NatomicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NatomicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=1,sticky="e")

          botonsolucion=Button(miframe3,text="Solucion")
          botonsolucion.grid(padx=10,pady=10)

          ventana2.mainloop()

     if lista_desplegable.get()=="N protones y N neutrones":
          
          ventana2=Tk()
          ventana2.title("N protones y N neutrones")

          miframe2=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe2.pack()

          miframe3=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe3.pack()

          Nmasico=Label(miframe2,text="N masico:")
          Nmasico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
          Natomico=Label(miframe2,text="N atomico:")
          Natomico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=0,sticky="w")

          NmasicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NmasicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=1,sticky="e")
          NatomicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NatomicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=1,sticky="e")

          botonsolucion=Button(miframe3,text="Solucion")
          botonsolucion.grid(padx=10,pady=10)

          ventana2.mainloop()

     if lista_desplegable.get()=="N electrones y N neutrones":
          
          ventana2=Tk()
          ventana2.title("N electrones y N neutrones")

          miframe2=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe2.pack()

          miframe3=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe3.pack()

          Nmasico=Label(miframe2,text="N masico:")
          Nmasico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
          Natomico=Label(miframe2,text="N atomico:")
          Natomico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=0,sticky="w")

          NmasicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NmasicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=1,sticky="e")
          NatomicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NatomicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=1,sticky="e")

          botonsolucion=Button(miframe3,text="Solucion")
          botonsolucion.grid(padx=10,pady=10)

          ventana2.mainloop()

     if lista_desplegable.get()=="N masico, N atomico y N neutrones":
          
          ventana2=Tk()
          ventana2.title("N masico, N atomico y N neutrones")

          miframe2=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe2.pack()

          miframe3=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe3.pack()

          Nmasico=Label(miframe2,text="N masico:")
          Nmasico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
          Natomico=Label(miframe2,text="N atomico:")
          Natomico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=0,sticky="w")

          NmasicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NmasicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=1,sticky="e")
          NatomicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NatomicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=1,sticky="e")

          botonsolucion=Button(miframe3,text="Solucion")
          botonsolucion.grid(padx=10,pady=10)

          ventana2.mainloop()

     if lista_desplegable.get()=="N masico, N atomico y N electrones":
          
          ventana2=Tk()
          ventana2.title("N masico, N atomico y N electrones")

          miframe2=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe2.pack()

          miframe3=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe3.pack()

          Nmasico=Label(miframe2,text="N masico:")
          Nmasico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
          Natomico=Label(miframe2,text="N atomico:")
          Natomico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=0,sticky="w")

          NmasicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NmasicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=1,sticky="e")
          NatomicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NatomicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=1,sticky="e")

          botonsolucion=Button(miframe3,text="Solucion")
          botonsolucion.grid(padx=10,pady=10)

          ventana2.mainloop()

     if lista_desplegable.get()=="N protones, N masico y N neutrones":
          
          ventana2=Tk()
          ventana2.title("N protones, N masico y N neutrones")

          miframe2=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe2.pack()

          miframe3=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe3.pack()

          Nmasico=Label(miframe2,text="N masico:")
          Nmasico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
          Natomico=Label(miframe2,text="N atomico:")
          Natomico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=0,sticky="w")

          NmasicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NmasicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=1,sticky="e")
          NatomicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NatomicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=1,sticky="e")

          botonsolucion=Button(miframe3,text="Solucion")
          botonsolucion.grid(padx=10,pady=10)

          ventana2.mainloop()

     if lista_desplegable.get()=="N masico, N electrones y N neutrones":
          
          ventana2=Tk()
          ventana2.title("N masico, N electrones y N neutrones")

          miframe2=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe2.pack()

          miframe3=Frame(ventana2)
          miframe3.pack()

          Nmasico=Label(miframe2,text="N masico:")
          Nmasico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=0,sticky="w")
          Natomico=Label(miframe2,text="N atomico:")
          Natomico.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=0,sticky="w")

          NmasicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NmasicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=0,column=1,sticky="e")
          NatomicoE=Entry(miframe2)
          NatomicoE.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=1,sticky="e")

          botonsolucion=Button(miframe3,text="Solucion")
          botonsolucion.grid(padx=10,pady=10)

          ventana2.mainloop()
     

ventana=Tk()
ventana.title("Calculadora")
ventana.geometry('300x70')

miframe=Frame(ventana)
miframe.pack()

miframe1=Frame(ventana)
miframe1.pack()

lista_desplegable=ttk.Combobox(miframe,width=33,state='readonly')
lista_desplegable.set("seleccione la opcion")
lista_desplegable.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=0)

opciones=["N masico y N atomico","N masico y N protones"
,"N masico y N electrones","N masico y N neutrones"
,"N atomico y N neutrones","N protones y N neutrones"
,"N electrones y N neutrones","N masico, N atomico y N neutrones"
,"N masico, N atomico y N electrones"
,"N protones, N masico y N neutrones"
,"N masico, N electrones y N neutrones"]
lista_desplegable['values']=opciones

boton=Button(miframe,text="iniciar",command=obtener_info)
boton.grid(padx=10,pady=10,row=1,column=1)

botonsalir=Button(miframe1,text="Salir",command=salir)
botonsalir.grid()


ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: No he entrado a mirar tu código en detalle (ahora no puedo), pero te puedo dar alguna pista para que vayas buscando. En alguna parte de tu código estás restando dos valores que tú crees que deberían ser números, pero son en realidad cadenas y eso te da el error. Posiblemente se trate de valores que has extraido de un campo de texto `Entry`. Debes convertirlos a entero con `int(dato)`

Comment: muchas gracias lo intentare

Comment: He probado el comentario de @abulafia y es correcto. Solo es necesario modificar el  dato de entrada a tipo `entero` y funciona correctamente. Justo en la línea 14 en `numneu=var1-var2`, modificar por `numneu=int(var1)-(var2)`. Buena respuesta @abulafia ;)

Answer (score 1):

como decía abulafia tienes que convertir los valores a int para que puedas realizar las operaciones

```
def obtener_info():
     if lista_desplegable.get()=="N masico y N atomico":
          def solucion():
               numneu= int(var1) - int(var2)
```